# Comparing times in bash not working and throwing syntax error

Tags: bash, scripting

```
#Run if time is between these two times
hour_first="19:59"
hour_last="22:01"
array_hosts=( "192.168.2.254;VPN one" "192.168.21.3;another vpn name" )
last_reset=""

reset_vpns(){
  current_time=$(date +%H:%M) # format :   HH:MM  with lead 0 if less than 10
  current_day=$(date +%j)
  echo $current_time
  echo $current_day
  
    if ! [[ "$current_day" -eq "$last_reset" ]]; then
        # if the current time is between the allow timeframe for resets
    if [[ "$current_time" > "$hour_first" ]] && [[ "$hour_last" > "$current_time" ]];then
        for element in "${array_hosts[@]}";do
        vpnname=$(echo "$element" | awk -F";" '{print $2}')
        echo "Daily Reset VPN: $vpnname "
        /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/bin/pfsense-vpnreset.php "$vpnname"
      done
      echo $current_day > $log_file
    fi
  fi
}

reset_vpns
```

My code above checks if the daily reset of my vpn's is needed.

However when I run it, I have the following syntax error for this line:

```
        if [[ "$current_time" > "$hour_first" ]] && [[ "$hour_last" > "$current_time" ]];then
```

Error:

```
main.sh: line 14: conditional binary operator expected
main.sh: line 14: syntax error near `"$hour_first"'
main.sh: line 14: `    if [[ "$current_time"  "$hour_first" ]]  [[ "$hour_last"  "$current_time" ]];then'
```

Also, where can I put the else for my second `if` ?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the `#!/bin/bash` (or whatever) as the first line of code, and how do you actually call your script?

Comment: Date arithmetic is easy if you use seconds since the beginning of time (1970).

Comment: @JeremyBoden Within `[[ ... ]]`, both `<` and `>` compares the sorting order of strings.

Comment: Your script does not produce the error message that you mention when running it with `bash`. Please update your question with your actual code.